# Autocomplete combobox .net doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-2008, combobox, autocomplete

this should be a simple issue! :-)

In a Winform I have a combobox that is populated at runtime, from a textfile, using LINQ code.

The combo contains a list of countries.

I set DropDown style to "DropDown"

Autocomplete mode to SuggestAppend (or Suggest, it doesn't change the behavior for me)
AutocompleteSource to ListItems

And when I run and enter some text in the form, NOTHING HAPPENS!

I must click the combo right arrow to see the list.

Any clue?

Comment: Yes it is... But no autocompletion

Comment: check ur items for any spaces before country names

Comment: Please share your code